# My navigation menu isn't completely centered for some reason

Tags: html, css, center, nav

My navigation menu is always **slightly off to the right** from the center point.

like such> https://i.stack.imgur.com/KELYB.png

```css
#nav {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1% 2% 1% 2%;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 5%;
  min-width: 50px;
}
#nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hard to tell... From the fiddle, it is because you left the default `padding-left` on the ul child of `#nav`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset default `ul` padding.

```
#nav ul { 
  padding: 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#nav {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1% 2% 1% 2%;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 5%;
  min-width: 50px;
}
#nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have unwanted padding to the left of your `ul` element.

This will fix it:

```
#nav ul { padding:0; }
```

[Fidde here](http://jsfiddle.net/soqqefay/)

Comment: thanks! would mark this as answer too but it seems only one is allowed, thus I marked the first responder.